# .NET Venn Diagram Library

Tags: c#, .net, diagram, charts, venn-diagram

Is there an open source or paid .NET library that will create diagrams with two important features:

- Create Venn Diagrams
- Save the diagrams as images?

Comment: Sounds like a good project to start.

Comment: The Google API Venn does not support https:. It renders out an img tag with a ref to their http: url only, which will give a mixed security warning if you are in an https protocol.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this was available in February.  But the Google chart API supports Venn diagrams: http://code.google.com/apis/chart/image/docs/chart_wizard.html

As an example: http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chs=200x80&cht=v&chd=t:100,50,80,20,10,20,5&chdl=DataA|DataB|DataC

Returns a Venn diagram with the following properties:

chr=200x80 (Size of image) (Can be a max of 300 000 pixels)
cht=v (Venn diagram type)
chd=t: (Size A, Size B, Size C, Size A intersect B, Size A intersect C, Size B intersect C, Size A intersect B intersect C)
chdl= (Labels of the data)

You can use this with 1, 2 or 3 circles.  (For two just make the size parameters -1 where C would be and only give two labels.

chart.apis.google.com/chart?chs=200x100&cht=v&chd=t:100,100,-1,10,-1,-1,-1&chdl=DataA|DataB

You can implement this in any application that can load an image and therefore save the result of this query.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of one that currently exists, but it shouldn't be that hard to create. One `Image` object to represent the chart. Use `Graphics.FillEllipse` to draw the circles, and `Graphics.DrawString`to print the statistics on the diagram. And the `Image.Save` method will save the chart to file.

Comment: Drawing the graphics seem like the easy part. Performing the calculations for overlap might not be that easy.

Comment: True enough. Using the alpha component of the brush would allow for overlap to work, but would also result in the rest of the shape becoming faded.